# Lomdus and Halacha

Tags: halacha, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, lomdus

To what degree are the works of R. Chaim Soloveichik and other 19th and 20th century "lamdanim" reckoned with by poskim?
I.e. are they generally accepted as providing correct interpretations of Gemara and Rishonim from which poskim will pasken.

Are they generally disputed in their understandings, or are they perhaps for the most part ignored.

(I have seem for example R. Ovadiah quote R. Chaim a few times, generally to argue with him, (but he quotes *everbody*).

What is the approach of other poskim e.g. R. Moshe, R. S.Z. Auerbach, R. Elyashiv, Rivevos Ephrayim, R. Wosner, R. Belsky, etc.

Comment: Around the same degree the poskim are reckoned with by the lamdanim.

Comment: Actually less. At least the lamdanim will quote a posek when building a premise.

Comment: What does "reckoned with" mean? Are you asking if a modern Posek ever cites R Soloveitchik?